# Multiply tensor with vector

Tags: matlab

```
A = ones(4,4,4);
b = [1,2,3,4];
```

I wish to multiply A with b in such a manner that,

```
ans(:,:,1) == ones(4,4)*b(1);
ans(:,:,2) == ones(4,4)*b(2);
```

etc.

Comment: Your example fails to show which dimension of `A` you multiply `b` along

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the following:

```
 A = ones(4,4,4);
 B = 1:4;

 C = shiftdim(B,-1);
 bsxfun(@times,A,C)
```

`Shiftdim` makes sure the vector is placed in the right dimension.  Then `bsxfun` makes sure the vector gets expanded to match the matrix, after which they can be properly multiplied.

If you struggle to understand this function, you may justs want to use a loop over the entities of `b` as that should allow you to get this result as well.

Comment: +1, I didn't realize right away that I actually answered pretty much the same as you did, only using `permute` instead of `shiftdim`. I'll keep it up there for reference =)

Comment: This answered the question perfectly, i already used bsxfun, but the shiftdim command enabled me to multiply with the correct dimension, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Dennis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26258444/2338750), you can combine [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html?refresh=true) like this:

```
bsxfun(@times, A, permute(b,[3 1 2]))
```

`permute` shifts the dimension of `b` so that it lies along the third dimension, and `bsxfun` makes sure the dimensions match when doing the multiplication.

I realize that you probably need to tweak this to make it fit your needs. Therefore, if you have a hard time understanding how `bsxfun`, `permute`, `shiftdim` etc. works, don't care about performance and don't intend using MATLAB the way it's supposed to be used... You can always do it using loops.

```
C = zeros(size(A));
for ii = 1:numel(b)
   C(:,:,ii) = A(:,:,ii)*b(ii);
end
```